# Add (change) a Widget's option

Tags: magento2, upgrade, widget

With a custom module, I have made some widgets that I added to my Magento 2 installation. I am using this module in several other projects.

I have added an option to the widget, an enabled/disabled option. The widget is only shown when the option reads 'enabled'.

When I update my Widget module in another project, this field is added. However, none of the widgets are shown, because the field 'enabled/disabled' is not yet in the database.

I know that I can programmatically change configuration, using `UpgradeData` and `$this->config>saveConfig('config change');`.

Is there a way to set all widgets to 'enabled', programmatically?

(I have tried SQL solutions, but it seems that the widget is generating HTML and Layout in several locations in the database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but it may be a solution to your problem.
Instead of naming the field "Enabled", name it "Disabled".
And invert your logic for displaying the widget.
Where you check `if (widget is enabled)...` check for `if (not widget is disabled)`.
This way, by default, all your widgets will be enabled when you install your extension and you get rid of the update problem.

Comment: Ofcourse! That's a very good solution to the problem, thanks!

Comment: I'll keep open the question, in case someone can help me with the original question.

Comment: As you wish. Side comment: I don't think you can do that fairly easily. Theoretically you can add widgets inside pages and static blocks and other entities that support a wysiwyg editor with widgets enabled. This means you need to go through all the db tables and fields that might support widgets and replace `{{widget ` with `{{widget enabled="1"`

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't feel like best practice. I am looking for a way to change these within the Models.

Comment: indeed this is not a good practice and it's pretty prone to errors. I don't think you can change this at models level because there are not any models involved. As you said in your question, the widgets are added as pieces of texts that are later parsed when some content is displayed.